# Adding data to mysql table in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

> This is the code for add action, This action adds subjectName(from subjects Table), totalMarks and Description (from SubjectMarks Table)

```
public function addAction() {
    $postArray = $this->params()->fromPost();
    $entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```

> This if condition is set true if data is entered and addbutton is clicked

```
    if (isset($postArray['submit']) && $postArray['subjectName']) {
        $subjectMarks = new SubjectMarks();


        $subjectMarks->setSubject(
            $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Subjects', $postArray['subjectName'])
        );

        $subjectMarks->setClasses(
            $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Classes', $postArray['classId'])
        );
        $subjectMarks->setSubject(
            $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Subjects', $postArray['subjectId'])
        );

        $subjectMarks->setTotalMarks($postArray['totalMarks']);
        $subjectMarks->setDescription($postArray['subjectMarksDesc']);
        $entityManager->persist($subjectMarks);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl().'/subjectmarks/totalmarks/index');
    }
```

> First else is executed that runs the query and sends data to 'add' view in form of 'data'

```
    else
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select(array(
            'subjectMarks.subjectMarkId as subjectMarkId',
            'subjectMarks.totalMarks as totalMarks',
            'subjectMarks.description as subjectMarksDesc',
            'subject.subjectId as subjectId',
            'subject.name as subjectName',
            'class.classId as classId',
        ))
            ->from('Application\Entity\SubjectMarks', 'subjectMarks')
            ->leftJoin('subjectMarks.subject', 'subject')
            ->leftJoin('subjectMarks.classes', 'class');
        $data = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();

        return new ViewModel(array(
                'data' => $data,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

> This is the code for add.phtml 'FORM' which is called when 'else' part executes and query selects the data required, and send the written data back, where it is received by if() condition.

```
<form name="myForm"   action="<?php echo $this->url('subjectmarks/totalmarks', array('action'=>'add'));?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="classId"   value="<?php echo $this->data[0]['classId'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="subjectId"  value="<?php echo $this->data[0]['subjectId'];?>">
<input type="text" name="subjectName"  >
<input type="text" name="totalMarks" >
<input  required="required" type="text" name="subjectMarksDesc" >

<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" >  <a style="color: white" href="<?php echo $this->basePath('subjectmarks/totalmarks/index');?>">Cancel</a></button>
<button type="submit" name="submit"   class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

The **Problem** is that `totalMarks` and `subjectMarkDesc` are added correctly, while the `subjectName` is taken id[0] of subject table, for any name that is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, as we can see that `subjectName` is inserted as input and `subjectId` is hidden, so there is *no direct relation* i.e, that clarify which `subjectName` is assigned to the `subjectId`.

So putting a `select` HTML tag will solve the problem, e.g

```
<select  name="addSubjectMarks">
<?php foreach ($this->data as $item):?>
```

> Here we can see subjectId and subjectName are related, unlike the question

```
    <option value="<?php echo $item['subjectId'];?> "> <?php echo    $item['subjectName'];?> </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

> Similarly there in the controller, inside the `if (isset($postArray['submit']) && $postArray['subjectName'])` condition, we will only replace this code

```
$subjectMarks->setSubject(
            $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Subjects', $postArray['addSubjectMarks'])
        );
```

> with this code

```
$subjectMarks->setSubject(
        $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Subjects', $postArray['subjectName'])
    );
 $subjectMarks->setSubject(
        $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Subjects', $postArray['subjectId'])
    );
```

> and it will perfectly. The select tag will output only those `subjectNames` which are already present in the subject Table.